# Costing out Azure App service options?

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps

Playing with Azure as a noob. Trying to work out how to cost the App Service correctly.

I notice when I add an app service, I have an option of "Web App + Database"

Does this cost the same as a Web App? or is it simply a wizard populating out a database as well as the Web App?

My goal is to work out the most cost-effective way to host a small laravel API in Azure.

Comment: Please do your homework. Azure's app service php + mysql tutorial has a step-by-step guide, after which you can see what got created, and what it is charging you. A better question would include further background information, like if platform as a service is a requirement, or if you wish to administer instances yourself for some reason.

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: No - I'm not asking about capacity... Also - Romeo Ninov - this is a business environment. John - I didn't see the step by step side sorry.. is there a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Web App + Database" option is just making it easier for you to deploy both resources and hook them up, you will be charged for the App Service and the database.

Comment: so in the costing page it would be an "App Service" and a "Msql Database" as services?

Comment: that is correct